# Topology with tuples

Tags: general-topology

Topology is defined by partions of a set, e.g. if $X$ is a set consisting of $\{a,b,c\}$, so one example would be:

$$
\mathcal{T} = \left\{\{a,b,c\},\{a,b\},\{a\},\emptyset\right\}
$$

However, order is often important in maths, so is there any similar definitions for tuples, where the order of the sets matter?

$$
\mathcal{T}_\circlearrowright = \left\{(a,b,c),(a,b),(a),\emptyset\right\}
$$

Would this have some applications, and does it have a name?

Comment: How would you "translate" the arbitrary unions and finite intersections conditions?

Comment: @ajotatxe Well it would make sense to have $(a,b,c)\cap(a,b) = (a,b)$, however I'm not sure about $(a,b,c)\cap(b,a)$. Perhaps $\emptyset$ or $-(a,b)$?

Comment: Tuples are typically not allowed to have infinite size. So you couldn't use this topology for almost anything that is interessting. So you yould have to potentially introduce infinite tuples aswell.

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak.  Tuples of any ordinal length are possible.

Comment: Yes, while tuples can be defined over arbitrary index sets, the situation becomes very ambiguous.  If we accept the OP's definition for the intersection of tuples for the finite-size case, what would the intersection of $(\ldots,5,3,1,2,4,6,\ldots)$ with itself be?  Recall that the shifting of the indices can cause trouble here.

Comment: It may be worth noting that, technical difficulties aside, mathematical structures are usually designed with the idea of capturing some notion within the formal language made by the structure. Topological spaces are meant to (opinion) capture the notion of "spatiality via proximity". What notion would a "tuple topology" be describing? Perhaps nonsymmetric topology in the sense of nonsymmetric metric spaces.